# Difference between io.quarkus and io.quarkus.platform

Tags: quarkus

What's the difference between the quarkus group-id `io.quarkus.platform` and `io.quarkus`?

In older versions (<2.0.0) the latter (without platform) was used. However, in the new sample projects the group-id `io.quarkus.platform` is used.

Comment: See: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/discussions/29031

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quarkus team is reorganizing the dependencies to create a more modular and maintainable project, with common dependencies organized in platform groups, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=smIVxLA-A0w) you can watch a video where they explain everything. As part of the on going changes they reorganized the boms so this is way you see the platform sufix.

**UPDATE1:** As @geoand pointed in this [link](http://quarkus.io/blog/quarkus-2x-platform-quarkiverse-registry) you can find a complete article about the ongoing changes regarding the quarkus bom and platforms.

Comment: https://quarkus.io/blog/quarkus-2x-platform-quarkiverse-registry/ is also probably worth mentioning

Comment: So, those two things are different? Or one is a newer name of the other?